# Vue typescript v-for type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

My template

```
<button v-for="group in groupList">
  <p>{{ group.name }}</p>
</button>
```

script:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

export interface IGroupTabData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

const props = defineProps<{ groupList: IGroupTabData[]; }>();

</script>
```

When I do `group.name` inside the template, it gives an warning `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

I solved it by type casting

```
<button v-for="group in groupList">
  <p>{{ (group as IGroupTabData).name }}</p>
</button>
```

But is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PropType** built-in vue.

```
import type { PropType } from "vue";

export interface IGroupTabData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

const props = defineProps({
  groupList: {
    type: Array as PropType<IGroupTabData[]>
  }
});
```

Comment: This project I am working on did not had tsconfig.json.
After creating one with basic options, the issue was gone.